# How to create a graph with two Y axis with different values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, google-spreadsheets

How do you make a scatter graph with 2 Y axis (one on the left and one on the right)? I have 2 scatter graphs that I want to combine. I need to have 2 lines, both lines have the same dependent variable but have their own independent variable. Click the link "graph" below to get an idea of what I'm looking for.

(I'm using google sheets but I can also find a computer with Excel if needed)

[image: graph]

Comment: This might not be a good idea, depending on how you intend to use this kind of chart.  It can mislead a viewer into making correlations between data that are not accurate, since the two Y axis hold no reasonable relationship.  You might consider using a correlative scatterplot graph instead, where you graph these two Y axis as Y and X, and each dot represents this graph's X axis.  Such a graph helps show if the two Y axis have any correlation in a very clear way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I have all my data in Excel:

[image: data]

Then I create my scatter graph from that data:

[image: scatter]

From there, I will double click one of the data points of my 2nd series:[image]

It will open the series properties, there I select to send it to the secondary axis:[image]

And voilà, you have your 1st series on the primary axis and 2nd series on the secondary axis:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given two series in a chart you can `Right Click > Change Chart Type... > Combo > Custom Combination`